# variable value not updating inside a do while loop

Tags: bash

I just started learning bash scripts and trying to practice loops and if statements so please bear with me. 
When I run the script I always get the print

```
You entered an invalid option.
```

No matter what option I select which means that the `loopControl` value hasn't changed.

```
loopControl="z"

echo "Choose one of the following options."

while [ "$loopControl" != "Q" ] && [ "$loopControl" != "q" ] do

    echo  "A"
    echo  "B"
    echo  "C"
    echo  "Q";
    read $loopControl

    if [ "$loopControl" == "A" ] || [ "$loopControl" == "a" ]
        then echo "option A works"
    elif [ "$loopControl" == "B" ] || [ "$loopControl" == "b" ]
        then echo "option B works"
    elif [ "$loopControl" == "C" ] || [ "$loopControl" == "c" ]
        then echo "option c works"
    else
        echo "You entered an invalid option."
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
read $loopControl
```

With:

```
read loopControl
```

Then, your code will work.

The complete script is:

```
$ cat script.sh
#!bin/bash
loopControl="z"
echo "Choose one of the following options."
while [ "$loopControl" != "Q" ] && [ "$loopControl" != "q" ]
do
    echo "A"
    echo "B"
    echo "C"
    echo "Q"
    read -r loopControl
    if [ "$loopControl" == "A" ] || [ "$loopControl" == "a" ]
    then
        echo "option A works"
    elif [ "$loopControl" == "B" ] || [ "$loopControl" == "b" ]
    then
        echo "option B works"
    elif [ "$loopControl" == "C" ] || [ "$loopControl" == "c" ]
    then
        echo "option c works"
    else
        echo "You entered an invalid option."
    fi
done
```

In operation, it works like:

```
$ bash script.sh 
Choose one of the following options.
A
B
C
Q
a
option A works
A
B
C
Q
B
option B works
A
B
C
Q
c
option c works
A
B
C
Q
q
You entered an invalid option.
```

#### Alternative:  Using `select`

The more conventional way to get a menu in `bash` is to use `select`:

```
$ cat script2.sh
#!bin/bash
loopControl="z"
echo "Choose one of the following options."
select loopControl in A B C Q
do
    case "$loopControl" in
        A) echo "option A works" ;;
        B) echo "option B works" ;;
        C) echo "option c works" ;;
        Q) exit ;;
        *) echo "You entered an invalid option." ;;
    esac
done
```

This works slightly differently:  One enters the number for an option.  But, the end result is quite similar:

```
$ bash script2.sh 
Choose one of the following options.
1) A
2) B
3) C
4) Q
#? 1
option A works
#? 3
option c works
#? 5
You entered an invalid option.
#? 4
$
```